# angular.js Getting the element from inside $evalAsync in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm finding that I'm using scope.$evalAsync inside a directive quite a lot.  Mainly to do DOM stuff/jquery plugins that need all the template {{vars}} compiled.

I can get at the scope object from inside $evalAsync but not the element.  In latest case in question, I'm manipulating  an element that gets rendered with an ngRepeat.  I'm currently getting the element by composing a jquery selector based on the scope object e.g.

```
scope.$evalAsync(function (scope) {
    $("#item-" + scope.id).runJQplugin();
})
```

Although this works, to me it would be more intuitive to be able to do this

```
scope.$evalAsync(function (scope,element) {
    element.runJQplugin();
})
```

Am I approaching this right or have  I misunderstood something fundamental with directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have access to the element from the link and the controller of a directive through the *closure* scope. So in link function:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    ...
    scope.$evalAsync(function(scope) {
        elem.runJQplugin();
    });
    ...
},
```

Controller (you need to specify the special `$element` dependency):

```
controller: ["$scope", "$element", function($scope, $element) {
    ...
    scope.$evalAsync(function(scope) {
        $element.runJQplugin();
    });
    ...
}],
```

Comment: I've tried the top example in my directive and I'm getting ReferenceError: elem is not defined

Comment: A fiddle/plunk would help.

Comment: Your right I tried a barebones version in fiddle and it works, yet revisiting my code it definitely doesn't.  So there's something weird I'm doing.  Oh well I'm using  $("#item-" + scope.id) for now.